# changing the content-type from application/octet to image/jpeg in MTOM message multipart requeste using jax-ws webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, content-type, mtom

While using the ImageUpload webservice exposed by .Net application I am getting a SOAP fault exception when i run it by generating client from WSImport and then sending the request. whereas with soap UI + MTOM the request just works perfect.

My code is given below.

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String remoteURL = "MyURL";
        String port = "";
        String imageFilePath = "";
        String imageName = "70d08e54-4a5e-4c95-88ba-4c791c2da55e.bmp";
        String correlationId = "70fd8ae9-56c9-43b3-b4d9-3d497da05b12";
        String createdTS = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
        String sentTS = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
        String from = "GUID";
        String messageId = "GUID";
        String sessionGUID = "GUID";
        try {
            URL serviceURL = new URL(remoteURL);
            ImageStoreService iImageStoreService = new ImageStoreService(
                    serviceURL);
            IImageStoreService service = iImageStoreService
                    .getBasicHttpBindingIImageStoreService(new MTOMFeature(true));
            // Cast the proxy to a BindingProvider
            BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) service;

            ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
            org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.phoenixinteractive_xpression_common.ObjectFactory objectFactoryCommon = new org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.phoenixinteractive_xpression_common.ObjectFactory();
            com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.ObjectFactory objectFactorySerialization = new com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.ObjectFactory();

            ImageStoreRequest imageStoreRequest = objectFactory.createImageStoreRequest();
            org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.phoenixinteractive_xpression_common.ImageStoreRequest imageStoreRequestData = objectFactoryCommon.createImageStoreRequest();
            MessageHeader messageHeader = objectFactoryCommon.createMessageHeader();
            messageHeader.setCorrelationID(correlationId);
            SimpleDateFormat sdfCreatedTS = new SimpleDateFormat(createdTS);
            String createdTSDate = sdfCreatedTS.format(new Date());
            SimpleDateFormat sdfSentTS = new SimpleDateFormat(sentTS);
            String sentTSDate = sdfSentTS.format(new Date());
            XMLGregorianCalendar cal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(createdTSDate);
            XMLGregorianCalendar calSent = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(sentTSDate);
            messageHeader.setCreatedTs(cal);
            messageHeader.setFrom(objectFactoryCommon.createMessageHeaderFrom(from));
            messageHeader.setMessageID(messageId);
            messageHeader.setSentTs(objectFactoryCommon.createMessageHeaderSentTs(calSent));

            imageStoreRequestData.setMessageHeader(objectFactoryCommon.createMessageHeader(messageHeader));
            imageStoreRequestData.setSessionGUID(sessionGUID);
            imageStoreRequestData.setMessageBody(objectFactoryCommon.createGenericMessageMessageBody("{"
                    + "\"IMAGE_UPLOAD_DATA\" : {"
                    + " \"SESSION_GUID\" : \"GUID\", "
                    + " \"FILES\" : { "
                    + " \"ImageName\" : \"MyImagePath\""
                    + " } "
                    + "}"
                +"}"));

            ImageData imgData = objectFactoryCommon.createImageData();

            imgData.setData(objectFactorySerialization.createBase64Binary(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Path","ImageName"))));
            imgData.setName(objectFactoryCommon.createImageDataName("ImageName"));

            ArrayOfImageData arrayOfImageData = objectFactoryCommon.createArrayOfImageData();
            List<ImageData> imgDataList = arrayOfImageData.getImageData();
            imgDataList.add(imgData);
            imageStoreRequestData.setImageDataList(objectFactoryCommon.createArrayOfImageData(arrayOfImageData));

            imageStoreRequest.setRequest(objectFactory.createImageStoreRequestRequest(imageStoreRequestData));

            System.out.println(imageStoreRequest.getRequest().getValue().getImageDataList());
            service.imageStoreRequest(imageStoreRequestData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error"+e);
        }
    }

}
```

After sending the request the multipart of the http request shows Content-type as application/octet i want to change it image/jpeg. Tried by adding MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS to bindingProvider.getRequestContext() Map but the request content-type still shows applcation/octet.

The wireshark recording is given below.

```
POST /ServerURL HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: multipart/related;start="<rootpart*b1894218-9121-46e1-b3e6-0d966c86ea12@example.jaxws.sun.com>";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:b1894218-9121-46e1-b3e6-0d966c86ea12";start-info="text/xml"
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
Host: systemtest
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37300


--uuid:b1894218-9121-46e1-b3e6-0d966c86ea12
Content-Id: <rootpart*b1894218-9121-46e1-b3e6-0d966c86ea12@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope>
    <S:Body>
        <ns4:ImageStoreRequest>
            <ns4:request>
                <ns2:MessageHeader>
                    <ns2:CorrelationID></ns2:CorrelationID>
                    <ns2:CreatedTs></ns2:CreatedTs>
                    <ns2:From></ns2:From>
                    <ns2:MessageID></ns2:MessageID>
                    <ns2:SentTs></ns2:SentTs>
                </ns2:MessageHeader>
                <ns2:MessageBody>{JSON Data}</ns2:MessageBody>
                <ns2:ArrayOfImageData>
                    <ns2:ImageData>
                        <ns5:base64Binary>
                            <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:89fe782f-78f5-4d63-b37d-69131a8df9a3@example.jaxws.sun.com"/>
                        </ns5:base64Binary>
                        <ns2:Name></ns2:Name>
                    </ns2:ImageData>
                </ns2:ArrayOfImageData>
                <ns2:SessionGUID></ns2:SessionGUID>
            </ns4:request>
        </ns4:ImageStoreRequest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
--uuid:b1894218-9121-46e1-b3e6-0d966c86ea12
Content-Id: <89fe782f-78f5-4d63-b37d-69131a8df9a3@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

ExifII*DuckyG+http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.0-c060 61.134777, 2010/02/12-17:32:00        "> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#" xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CS5 Macintosh" xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:FC9787C7C6F211E182C9CE33D84E1927" xmpMM:DocumentID="xmp.did:FC9787C8C6F211E182C9CE33D84E1927"> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:FC9787C5C6F211E182C9CE33D84E1927" stRef:documentID="xmp.did:FC9787C6C6F211E182C9CE33D84E1927"/> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta> <?xpacket end="r"?>&Adobed

$@Bbb





--uuid:b1894218-9121-46e1-b3e6-0d966c86ea12--
```